# display 15-minute steps between two given times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, loops

I have an appointments table which saves 2 times. start and end. I want to display all appointments in 15 minute steps. e.g. given 10am /11am, now display me 10.15, 10.30, 10.45 in my view! Thx for advise!

```
-@appointment.each do |form|  
  =form.date  
  =form.start_time  
  =form.end_time
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have an one-liner, but is this what you really want? And hopefully the delta between this two dates isn't too big, the code below isn't very efficient.

```
(Time.now.to_i..1.hour.from_now.to_i).to_a.in_groups_of(15.minutes).collect(&:first).collect { |t| Time.at(t) }
```

---

Better solution:

```
# Your variables
time_start = Time.now
time_end = time_start + 1.hour
[time_start].tap { |array| array << array.last + 15.minutes while array.last < time_end }
```

---

I added `to` to Ruby's `Time` instance methods:

```
class Time
  def to(to, step = 15.minutes)
    [self].tap { |array| array << array.last + step while array.last < to }
  end
end
```

so you end up with code like this:

```
time_start.to(time_end)
```

All three solutions will end in an array containing `Time` objects of steps.

```
 => [2011-07-22 17:11:11 +0200, 2011-07-22 17:26:11 +0200, 2011-07-22 17:41:11 +0200, 2011-07-22 17:56:11 +0200, 2011-07-22 18:11:11 +0200]
```

Comment: props for .in_groups_of(15.minutes) ... that's nice!

Comment: I think this solution is more efficient - http://stackoverflow.com/a/29985773/3101782

Answer (score 12):

you just need to pass option **:minute_step => 15** to the input fields

Comment: yes I have this parameter in my input field. but this is another view which lists available appointments.

Comment: I did not get your question. Are you asking what should be the query to retrieve appointments between 10:00 AM and 11:00 AM?

Comment: no just display me the time steps between 2 given times like in the example in my question

Comment: If you are saving appointments with minute_step then start_time would be 10:00 , 10:15, 10:30, 10:45 right. You may just need to render **link_to appointmnet.start_time, appointment_path**

Comment: no they are not saved with steps. just a start time and end time. and I want to create 15-minute steps between those in my view :)

Comment: Confused did not get your question. Can you elaborate more