# Iterating between two DateTimes, with a one hour step

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm looking for an efficient way, in Ruby 1.9.x/Rails 3.2.x, to iterate between two DateTime objects, with a one-hour step.

```
('2013-01-01'.to_datetime .. '2013-02-01'.to_datetime).step(1.hour) do |date|
   ...
end
```

I understand that an issue with this is that `1.hour` is just the number of seconds, but my attempts to convert that to a DateTime object and use that as the step doesn't work either.

I looked at "[Beware of Ruby Sugar](http://alindeman.github.com/2011/01/22/beware-of-ruby-syntactic-sugar.html)". It mentions, near the bottom, that DateTime has a direct `step` method. I confirmed this by running `methods` on a DateTime object, but I cannot find any documentation on `step` in DateTime, in either Ruby's or Rails' documents.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Similar to my answer in "[How do I return an array of days and hours from a range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680425/how-do-i-return-an-array-of-days-and-hours-from-a-range/11680898#11680898)", the trick is to use `to_i` to work with seconds since the epoch:

```
('2013-01-01'.to_datetime.to_i .. '2013-02-01'.to_datetime.to_i).step(1.hour) do |date|
  puts Time.at(date)
end
```

Note that `Time.at()` converts using your local time zone, so you may want to specify UTC by using `Time.at(date).utc`

Comment: This solution will work in case of `1.hour` and `1.day`, but not if interval is `1.month`. As `1.month` is always 30 days in Rails.

Comment: That's not quite right. 1.month in isolation is 2592000 seconds however (in Rails) when combined with a date and addition/subtraction, x.months actually supports months properly. May not help in the above, but it's something to keep in mind. So to do the above you can't really do the array approach but rather go with a while loop. Ala:

```ruby
date =  DateTime.parse("2013-01-01"); 
finish = DateTime.parse("2015-02-01");
while(date < finish) do; puts Time.at(date); date += 1.month; end;
```

Comment: And for anyone who need rounded to the hour see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20805972/5783745)

Comment: You'll also need to use `.each` / `.map` or whatever you need after the `.step` call.

Answer (score 17):

Maybe late but, you can do it without Rails, for example to step with hours:

Ruby 2.1.0

```
require 'time' 

hour_step = (1.to_f/24)

date_time = DateTime.new(2015,4,1,00,00)
date_time_limit = DateTime.new(2015,4,1,6,00)

date_time.step(date_time_limit,hour_step).each{|e| puts e}

2015-04-01T00:00:00+00:00
2015-04-01T01:00:00+00:00
2015-04-01T02:00:00+00:00
2015-04-01T03:00:00+00:00
2015-04-01T04:00:00+00:00
2015-04-01T05:00:00+00:00
2015-04-01T06:00:00+00:00
```

Or minutes:

```
#one_minute_step = (1.to_f/24/60)

fifteen_minutes_step = (1.to_f/24/4)

date_time = DateTime.new(2015,4,1,00,00)
date_time_limit = DateTime.new(2015,4,1,00,59)

date_time.step(date_time_limit,fifteen_minutes_step).each{|e| puts e}

2015-04-01T00:00:00+00:00
2015-04-01T00:15:00+00:00
2015-04-01T00:30:00+00:00
2015-04-01T00:45:00+00:00
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

Here's something I came up with recently:

```
require 'active_support/all'

def enumerate_hours(start, end_)
  Enumerator.new { |y| loop { y.yield start; start += 1.hour } }.take_while { |d| d < end_ }
end

enumerate_hours(DateTime.now.utc, DateTime.now.utc + 1.day)
# returns [Wed, 20 Aug 2014 21:40:46 +0000, Wed, 20 Aug 2014 22:40:46 +0000, Wed, 20 Aug 2014 23:40:46 +0000, Thu, 21 Aug 2014 00:40:46 +0000, Thu, 21 Aug 2014 01:40:46 +0000, Thu, 21 Aug 2014 02:40:46 +0000, Thu, 21 Aug 2014 03:40:46 +0000, Thu, 21 Aug 2014 04:40:46 +0000, Thu, 21 Aug 2014 05:40:46 +0000, Thu, 21 Aug 2014 06:40:46 +0000, Thu, 21 Aug 2014 07:40:46 +0000, Thu, 21 Aug 2014 08:40:46 +0000, Thu, 21 Aug 2014 09:40:46 +0000, Thu, 21 Aug 2014 10:40:46 +0000, Thu, 21 Aug 2014 11:40:46 +0000, Thu, 21 Aug 2014 12:40:46 +0000, Thu, 21 Aug 2014 13:40:46 +0000, Thu, 21 Aug 2014 14:40:46 +0000, Thu, 21 Aug 2014 15:40:46 +0000, Thu, 21 Aug 2014 16:40:46 +0000, Thu, 21 Aug 2014 17:40:46 +0000, Thu, 21 Aug 2014 18:40:46 +0000, Thu, 21 Aug 2014 19:40:46 +0000, Thu, 21 Aug 2014 20:40:46 +0000, Thu, 21 Aug 2014 21:40:46 +0000]
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not entirely sure if this will help out but check out this stack overflow page, question seems similar.

[calculate difference in time in days, hours and minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6943692/calculate-difference-in-time-in-days-hours-and-minutes)