# How do get a random DateTime rounded to beginning of hour in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, datetime

Basically I'd like to get a random datetime within the last year:

```
rand(1.year).ago  #=> Sun, 22 Sep 2013 18:37:44 UTC +00:00 (example)
```

But how do I go about specifying or limiting this to times on the hour? For example:

```
Sun, 22 Sep 2013 18:00:00 UTC +00:00
Sat, 02 Nov 2013 10:00:00 UTC +00:00
Fri, 12 Apr 2013 21:00:00 UTC +00:00
```

Comment: You mean that you want to ensure that the random time generated are on exact hour chimes?

Comment: Yes. Or that I round these times to the nearest hour.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I finally found what I was looking for. @Stoic's answer is very good but I found this available method (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html):

```
rand(1.year).ago.beginning_of_hour
```

Does exactly the same thing but looks neater and prevents you from having to write your own function.

Comment: really nice :) wasn't aware about the existence of `beginnning_of_*` methods.

Comment: Calling #ago on a number is deprecated in ruby 2.1.2.  now use `rand(1.year).seconds.ago.beginning_of_hour`

Comment: @andorov `ago` is actually a part of ActiveSupport, not core ruby. Calling it on a number was deprecated in 4.1 and disallowed in 4.2.

Comment: @Kelvin quite right, thanks for the correction - won't let me edit my comment.

Comment: This answer rounds down, not to the nearest hour.  @andorov's answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 24):

Rounding datetime to the nearest hour in Rails would be

```
(DateTime.now + 30.minutes).beginning_of_hour
```

Not the answer to the actual question, but it does answer the title of the question (which is how i got here).

Comment: which equals `30.minutes.from_now.beginning_of_hour`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
def random_time_to_nearest_hour
  time = rand(1.year).ago
  time - time.sec - 60 * time.min
end
```

Examples:

```
[1] pry(main)> random_time_to_nearest_hour
=> Sun, 28 Apr 2013 16:00:00 UTC +00:00
[2] pry(main)> random_time_to_nearest_hour
=> Sat, 08 Jun 2013 15:00:00 UTC +00:00
[3] pry(main)> random_time_to_nearest_hour
=> Thu, 22 Aug 2013 23:00:00 UTC +00:00
[4] pry(main)> random_time_to_nearest_hour
=> Tue, 29 Jan 2013 14:00:00 UTC +00:00
[5] pry(main)> random_time_to_nearest_hour
=> Tue, 13 Aug 2013 06:00:00 UTC +00:00
[6] pry(main)> random_time_to_nearest_hour
=> Mon, 03 Jun 2013 08:00:00 UTC +00:00
[7] pry(main)>
```

Note that, this method will always `floor` down to the nearest hour, but since you are anyways generating a random time, it wont matter if this time is getting `floor'ed` down or getting `round'ed`. :)

Comment: Check the answer I found.