# Custom minutes ranges in date input Simple Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, input, simple-form

I use SimpleForm for creating forms inside my Rails app. For datetime I use default format from SimpleForm. All is ok, except - I need minutes with gaps, like - 1:00, 1:15, 1:30, 1:45, 2:00.

Is this possible without creating custom input?

Comment: Are you asking how to create a select with these values or how to "round" user input to these values?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783589/display-15-minute-steps-between-two-given-times.

Answer (score 5):

Yep. Use code like this:

```
f.input :time, as: :time, :minute_step => 15
```

Comment: `f.input :time, minute_step: 15` should be enough. `as: :time` is not necessary.